# Distorting part of a UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, graphics, transform

I have an interesting problem. Hopefully there's an interesting solution :)

I have a UIScrollView view that takes up the width of the iPad screen. The content of the scrollview is, obviously, wider.

Now, I'd like to apply a transformation to the visible part (that is, the screen area) of the scroll view to gently curve up the two ends.

Thus, there are two issues:

1) Is such a transformation possible at all? Essentially I want to shift the left and right side up a little and have the top and bottom edges of the view curved as required such that the middle points don't move.

2) I don't wish to apply this to the contents of the scroll view since the effect would be lost when scrolled out of view. Instead I wish to apply the result to the parent container. Would this work?

Here's a graphic:

[image]

Tim

Comment: Surely someone can help?

Comment: Can you provide some sort of graphic to show what you are looking for? I have read this a few times, and I'm not sure I understand the two "issues" or objectives that you stated. (And it's not obvious that the content of the scrollview is wider than the width of the screen.) Restating you objectives might get more attention. But a graphic will help a lot, too.

Comment: Hi. Perhaps this will help: Imagine that the scroll view contains a long horizontal clothes line. I want the line to curve upwards at the ends of the visible window as defined by the scrollview's frame. As you scroll, you'll always see that same curvature applied to the visible area.

Comment: @tarmes, Still don't have a concrete image of what you want. Maybe post a mock-up image will greatly help us understand what you need. And also you get a greater possibility that your problem can get a solution sooner.

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess, but how about using an ordinary image on top of your scroll view? The image could show the "distortion" effect while the underlaying view would be left untouched.

Comment: Hi. The problem is that I want to see the distortion applied to the contents of the scroll view as it's scrolled. The even bigger problem is that I don't know how to set up a distortion of the type I'd described.

Comment: or even better to have the image behind the scrollview.

Comment: can u use the decceleration of the scroll view delegate method and do the animation manually? you have to trick it somehow...

Answer (score 1):

On desktop OS X this would be possible using a `CIFilter` on a `CALayer` . However according to the  [CALayer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> While the CALayer class exposes this property, Core Image is not available in iOS. Currently the filters available for this property are undefined.

Your best bet would be to implement this using an OpenGL fragment shader yourself. The tricky part is to get access to the contents of the view in the region you wish to transform in real time.

I have yet to see anything operating on live (scrolling) content on iOS. All similar animations like the Mail.app trash can animation, page curls, etc operate on static content (as in, a view rendered to an image just once, then transform that image).

Currently the only way I see this possible is:

- Render the view region to an image at a certain interval
- Transform using your opengl shader
- Render the opengl output on top of the actual content.

Because you would have to poll the view, render to image and render that as an OpenGL view that only covers a part of the main screen I expect the performance to be sub optimal.

Comment: Hmm, I'm happy to pre-render the entire contents of the scroll view if that provides a simplified solution. However, I know nothing about OpenGL. Can you provide, or point me to, any code that would perform the type of distortion that I'm describing?

Comment: Using pre-rendered content would actually be helpful. You would have to synchronize scrolling with the opengl animation, but that would be easy using the UIScrollView's scrollViewDidScroll delegate method. As for the actual transform, take a look at existing OpenGL/shader projects that try to mimic page curls. One open-source example would be PaperStrack: http://api.mutado.com/mobile/paperstack/ . That page also links to mesh deformation & OpenGL ES pages.

Comment: Actually, as of iOS5, Core Image is available.

Comment: @c.cam108 - correct, CIFilter is available on iOS 5. But you cannot apply those to layer contents yet. It's also not possible to create a custom CIFilter (as needed to accomplish this effect).

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

(1)

Drawing a CALayer on top of scrollview with less opacity and which will create the rounded corner effect to the ScrollView.

Cons: Rendering of CALayers is way too slow for this use (especially on the older devices), it is not very good to use in games etc. You could switch to UIImages or cocos2d sprites, another option is to create your own layer class with OpenGL, although that one isnt quite as simple. Hope one of those options work for you.

(2)

Is the content behind your scroll view (what’s being displayed under the rounded-off corners) a solid color or otherwise static? If so, you should be able to get way better performance by overlaying “corner” graphics—translucent at their center, and opaque (with your background color or whatever) at their edges—on top of the corners of your scroll view. The cost of compositing four 11x11 images over your content will be dramatically less than that of clipping it.

Cons: Not known :)

(3)

```
scrollView.layer.cornerRadius = 11;
scrollView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

This works perfectly fine for the iPhone 4.
Cons: Does not work perfectly in iPhone 3GS,3G and iPod.

Comment: Hi - I'm not looking for a rounded corner effect at all :(

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea! In theory you can't "warp" your view by matrix (with matrices it's possible to make only line-to-line transformations.

As a workaround you can divide your top and bottom screen areas with thin views. Set vertical scale of these views: 8x (for example) for the closest to screen border one, then 4x, 2x... Then render your long scroll-view into some offscreen container. And map parts of this container to thin views. I don't know how to do it with UIKit API, but it's working solution for OpenGL based graphics.